# NodeJS: переменные окружения и Windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-7

Изучаю *NodeJS*, проект развернул в *WebStorm*, там я добавлял некоторые переменные в параметрах запуска ноды в enviroment variables, например `NODE_PATH`, `NODE_ENV`.

Так вот в *WebStorm'e* все работает, а когда я пытаюсь запустить проект из консоли, нода ругается что не может найти нужные модули. Я так подозреваю, что дело в том что в *WebStorm* у меня `" NODE_PATH = . "` - это говорит ноде где искать модули, а когда из консоли я запускаю - то она не понимает и не знает ничего об этом. Так это или нет?

p.s. Добавил `NODE_PATH` с параметром `"."` в переменные среды - ничего не изменилось

Comment: а какую конкретно ошибку пишет node ???? может node не прописанна в системных переменных Path ?? "Прав кноп Vairb на Мой компьютер -> Свойства -> дополнительные параметры ->переменные среды -> системные переменные (Path)" там должен быть путь к Node

Comment: А может просто пути  в скриптах не так прописанны, я когда изучал Node напарывался на такие моменты, просто WebStorm скрывает это подкладывая пути

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В windows указывать переменные окружения для node.js приложения можно, например, так:

```
set TEST_VALUE="A value" && node index.js
```

А вот так может выглядеть содержимое файла index.js

```
console.log('The test value is ' + process.env.TEST_VALUE);
```

Если говорить о вашем конкретном случае, то можно использовать:

```
set NODE_PATH="." && node index.js
```

Comment: Это нужно делать всегда? Можно ли это все в файл какой-то писать а при запуске что он читался?

Comment: Ну чтобы при каждом запуске из консоли не устанавливать эти переменные

Comment: Можно, например, сделать .bat файл и каждый раз запускать его вместо `node index.js`.

Comment: А как в линуксе это будет? так же само? (например ubuntu)

Comment: В *nix другой синтаксис установки переменных окружения, а именно `TEST_VAR="A value" node index.js`. Ну и придется использовать bash скрипт вместо batch скрипта windows.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить таким образом. Пишется прямо в консоли
 `set NODE_PATH=C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules`
Путь до модулей разумеется свой.

Answer (score 0):

Введите абсолютный путь в NODE_PATH

Comment: Куда именно? NODE_PATH = . у меня прописывается в настройках webstorm, а я хочу запустить из под cmd

Comment: Попробуйте в webstorm пописать и проверьте  видит ли винда эту переменную. Если не увидит, то пропишите в ещё в оукружении самой винды.